# Is there a better approach of splitting two different characters of a string

Tags: python-2.7

I have this string  that contains two different characters '*' and '.' .  What I wanted to do is to separate them and append them to a list.

example:

```
myString='*.***...***.*.*...***..'
```

output would be like this:

```
myList=['*','.','***','...','***','.','*','.','*','...','***','..']
```

so far I have a solution for this but it's not the best solution yet.

here is my code:

```
from re import findall

myString='*.***...***.*.*...***..'

a=findall(r'[*]+',myString)
b=findall(r'[.]+',myString)

myList=[]

for i in xrange(len(a)):
    myList+=a[i],b[i]

print myList
```

It is guaranteed that len(a)==len(b) .

Now my problem is that my solution is slow especially when the length of myString is very large. 
Is there a way to optimize this?

Thanks for reading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works faster:

```
myString = '*.***...***.*.*...***..'

def intersperse(lst, item):
    result = [item] * (len(lst) * 2 - 1)
    result[0::2] = lst
    return result

result = [item for item in intersperse(myString.split('.'), '.') if item]
```